# Excel VBA Macro to output multiple PDFs based on column value

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to setup a VBA macro in Excel that outputs a PDF for every set of rows with the same account number.  I am tailoring this from a macro found for a similar purpose.  I have two sheets, Data and Account.  The Data sheet has the unfiltered data [A0, MTIME, MDATE, MINIT, MTEXT] as the row headers and the Account sheet just has the unique account numbers I want to pull.

The filtering appears to work correctly but the macro is dying at the first output component and I am a bit stumped as to why.  Have verified permissions are good.  Any thoughts would be apprecaited.  Code Below.

```
Sub PracticeToPDF()
'Prepared by Dr Moxie

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws_unique As Worksheet
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim iLastRow_unique As Long
Dim UniqueRng As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Note that the macro will save the pdf files in this active directory so you should save in an appropriate folder
DirectoryLocation = ActiveWorkbook.Path

Set ws = Worksheets("Data") 'Amend to reflect the sheet you wish to work with
Set ws_unique = Worksheets("Account") 'Amend to reflect the sheet you wish to work with

'Find the last row in each worksheet
iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
iLastRow_unique = ws_unique.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


With ws
    'I've set my range to reflect my headers which are fixed for this report
    Set DataRange = ws.Range("$A$1:$E$" & iLastRow)

    'autofilter field is 4 as I want to print based on the practice value in column D
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=1

    Set UniqueRng = ws_unique.Range("A1:A20" & iLastRow_unique)
    For Each Cell In UniqueRng
        DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Cell

    Name = DirectoryLocation & "\" & Cell.Value & " Account Notes" & ".pdf"

    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Name _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Next Cell

End With
With ws
     .Protect Userinterfaceonly:=True, _
     DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
    True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
     .EnableOutlining = True
     .EnableAutoFilter = True
     If .FilterMode Then
        .ShowAllData
     End If
 End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it, and it works. What do you mean by dying? An error dialog? What is the error message?

Comment: The line starting with Set UniqueRng makes the code very inefficient because you concatenate the last row's number to A1:A20, so if the last row is 100, then you iterate for 20100 items. Remove the 20. And improve your indentation, it's hard to read it.

Comment: What do the cells of the Account sheet contain? Are their characters legal in filenames?

Comment: On the Name = line the application crashes with a 1004 error.

Comment: The account cells contain 6 digit numbers

Comment: When it 'crashes', Press Ctrl+G (Immediate Window), and type ? DirectoryLocation[Enter] ? Cell.Value[Enter] Those two can cause problem, my bet is on the first one.

Comment: This gives me a "You typed an invalid name for a sheet or chart

Comment: Which one, the first or the second line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

z32a7ul put me on the right track with some items I had to correct.  The ultimate issue was I had the macro built out on the sheet level and not as a module.  Moved the code to the module and combined with the edits got it up and going.  Thanks z32a7ul!